# Android - Sending an SMS on button click.

Tags: android, onclick, sms

So I am trying to make my app send an SMS automatically to the given number when the user presses the button.

I can make it open the messenger and write the text but I can't make it send it automatically.

My code is as follows (The part that matters I guess);

```
@Override
public void onClick(View a) {


    if(a.equals(sms)){
        tekst = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
        Uri tlf = Uri.parse("smsto:"+tekst.getText().toString());
        Intent c = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, tlf);
        c.setData(tlf);
        c.putExtra("sms_body","Hjelp jeg er i fare!" );
        startActivity(c);



    }else{
        tekst = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
        Intent c = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        Uri tlf = Uri.parse("tel:"+tekst.getText().toString());
        c.setData(tlf);
        startActivity(c);


    }

}
```

So, how can I make it send the SMS?

BTW, I have added the permission: "android.permission.SEND_SMS"

Comment: You should take another approach that interfaces with `SmsManager` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html) rather than creating an intent that's consumed by the default SMS app.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
String phoneNumber = "<phone_number_here>";
String message = "Test Message";
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
```

Notice that it's a very simple snip code that you can implement more.
If you want to see SMS showing up in any of the other SMS Clients/Apps installed yuo must use:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
values.put("address", "<phone_number_here>"); 
values.put("body", "Test Message"); 
getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
```

and add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 try {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage([number], null, [sms], null, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();

  }
```

where [number] is the number to which you want to send your sms and [sms] is your text you wanna send

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
//Declare the button and the tetviews to input number and the message
Button sendSMSBtnBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
txtphoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhoneNo);
txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSMS);

//Calling the method sendSMSMessage in the button click event
sendSMSBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View view) {
            sendSMSMessage();
         }
 });}

// Method to send SMS using SMS Manager
protected void sendSMSMessage() {
      Log.i("Send SMS", "");

      String phoneNo =  txtphoneNo.getText().toString();
      String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();

      try {
         SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
         smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
         "SMS faild, please try again.",
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
```

Note : Make sure you have the set the following permission in the Manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```